# What is the correct way of installing virtualenv for Python?

Tags: ubuntu, python3, virtualenv

What is the correct way of installing virtualenv for Python?
Should I do `sudo apt-get install python3-virtualenv` or `pip3 install virtualenv`?
I'm using Ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: Do you even need virtualenv? `python3 -m venv` would work just as well

Comment: For the general choice `apt-get` or `pip`: https://askubuntu.com/questions/431780/apt-get-install-vs-pip-install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both options are correct. It depends on which package manager you want to keep track of this package: `apt` or `pip`.

Whichever one you choose, then you'll need to update it from there in the future. This question is opinion based. In my opinion, I would install it with `apt`. This way, whenever you upgrade your entire system, the `virtualenv` python package/module will also be upgraded.